# Calculating growth rate with null values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with the following columns: Country, Year (10 columns ranging from 2005 to 2015) with country names, and a numerical percent value under each year representing GDP.

I am trying to calculate the growth rate from 2005 to 2015, but my data is from the UN website and so incomplete - it has null values. I was wondering how to calculate the growth rate in SQL while accounting for null values?

Comment: Could you not interpolate the missing values?

Comment: i could, but some of them have values only for one year, and interpolating to see growth would defeat the purpose.

Comment: With questions like these, it helps to include sample data with actual data values. Are looking for a growth rate definition when period values are missing? Or is there something specific to mysql at issue?

Comment: @katebeckett Why don't you read all the values in, and use an interpolation algorithm to guess the values? For example, if you have a single value and the rest null, you can assume the average of the values, which is the single data point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning so sorry if i've missed the question. You want to run an average of the former year and latter year to the null value to get an interpolated value to fill it in, such as the following

```
UPDATE [table1]
SET [GDP_YEAR_N] = 
CASE WHEN [GDP_YEAR_N-1] IS NOT NULL AND [GDP_YEAR_N+1] IS NOT NULL
THEN AVG(SELECT GDP_YEAR_N-1,GDP_YEAR_N+1 FROM [TABLE1] T WHERE T.country =
O.Country ) END 
FROM [Table1] O
WHERE [GDP_YEAR_N] IS NULL
```

Otherwise you can just ignore the null value in your data. If you're graphing the data the you can extrapolate a value from the difference in the former and latter years. If someone has a much smarter idea please let me know, i'm interested as well